# How do bare clauses beginning with "in which" work?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

The [latest Stack Exchange blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/) contains the following section header:

> In which we stop being dumb

I have never really understood what is going on in these "in which..." constructions at a grammatical level. Is it just an elision of something like "this is a section in which..."? Or, perhaps, is it an imitation of a famous quotation/title/etc. that has the same structure?

I feel like I've only seen this construction on the internet, which suggests to me that it is either a piece of internet lingo that I've somehow missed or a very new construction that hasn't caught up to me yet. I am a native speaker of American English, but am relatively ignorant of other varieties, so perhaps this is just a feature of BrE that I'm unaware of or something.

---

Note that I am *not* asking about constructions like:

> In which of these two fields should I write my name?

These constructions are full sentences in which the preposition "in" has been hoisted to the beginning of the sentence, and I understand them perfectly well.

Comment: I take it you've never read A.A. Milne (Winnie the Pooh)  You should read these as an ellipsis of *[A chapter or story or tale] in which...* E.g., [*In which Pooh and Piglet Go Hunting and Nearly Catch a Woozle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winnie-the-Pooh_%28book%29)

Comment: So I assume you're asking for more info about the relative clause that uses "which", and not about the interrogative clause that uses "which". . .

Comment: @F.E. Well, in particular, about this specific usage of the relative clause, in which the referent(?) of the clause isn't present. If this is really is just ellipsis of _[A chapter or story or tale]_, as Jim states, that's basically the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: It seems so, that the antecedent is ellipted out, and the reader is expected to understand from the context what the understood antecedent is supposed to be. This falls in line with the examples that Jim had provided.

Comment: Isn't this used to denoting a clause that is conditional due to the subject? *Martial artists hone their skills in which to successfully defeat their opponents.* In order for martial artists to defeat their opponent, they need to hone their skills. As far as I can tell, these usually need the subject to be plural.

Comment: @Tucker If you were to consider your example *"Martial artists hone their skills in which to successfully defeat their opponents"* to be similar in form to *"I'm looking for an essay question with which to challenge the brighter students"*, then you might be interested in the topic of *infinitival relative clauses*.

Comment: @F.E. Thank you very much. I will look into that. Google can't seem to point out good references though.

Comment: @Tucker You're welcome. One of the wikipedia pages has a little bit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses#Nonfinite_relative_clauses but not much info. (Internet as a grammar source is rather iffy anyway, as their info is a mishmash of different grammars, and usually have bad info in there.) If you have a copy of the 2002 *CGEL* by Huddleston and Pullum et al., then there's related info on page 1067-8. The older 1985 *CGEL* by Quirk et al. might have some info too, but it's hard to tell from their subject index.

Comment: @F.E. Thank you for these resources. I'll buy a copy of 2002 CGEL (my wife is a Cambridge alum).

Comment: Changed my mind on the contradicting everyone. It isn't worth it.  For those of you who can understand this, it is the difference between an adjective clause and a prepositional phrase with a noun clause functioning as the object of the preposition.  Both take the same function through different structures: "which we looked in" vs "in which we looked".  Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it just an elision of something like "this is a section in which..."?

When used as a title of a section or story, yes. Jim's comment notes A. A. Milne's frequent usage of this pattern in Winnie the Pooh: "In which Pooh and Piglet Go Hunting and Nearly Catch a Woozle."

This usage could be assumed to say:

> [The chapter] in which Pooh and Piglet Go Hunting and Nearly Catch a Woozle.

More generically, "in which" simply refers to something that happened "in" another thing:

> He kept attempting counterarguments -- in which he repeatedly committed the same fallacies.

The chapter/title usage actually fits this pattern *if* you are reading a full table of contents:

> Chapter 3 — In Which Pooh and Piglet Go Hunting and Nearly Catch a Woozle.

Explicitly noting the chapter or section number is not necessary in modern writing (especially on the internet) and so you are left with just the heading starting with "in which".

Comment: Might add that the construction is self-consciously old-fashioned to create a humorous effect.